# VBA code to delete entire rows if #N/A were found simultaneously in columns A, B & C

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a code which will look at specific sheets at row values in columns A, B and C and if the values in the row are simultaneously in 3 columns A, B and C equal to the "#N/A" then the entire row will be deleted, but if in the row in columns A, B and C there is no errors then it won't be cleared. I have written below code, but it doesn't work. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!.

```
Sub CleanNA()
Dim ws As Variant
Dim x As Long

ws = Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")
    For x = 0 To UBound(ws)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws(x)).Activate
        If IsError(Range("A:C").Value) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws(x)).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Clear
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws(x)).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Clear
        End If
        Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("#N/A were successfully cleaned")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows, or clear them?

Comment: @TimWilliams I want to clear all values in the row if #N/A was found simultaneously in a row in columns A, B and C

Comment: Are you using ranges or table objects? Can you post an image of your sheets? It' possible to add a new helper column to count the #N/A in each row and then clear the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub CleanNA()
    
    Dim allSheets As Variant
    Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    allSheets = Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")
    For x = 0 To UBound(allSheets)
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(allSheets(x))
        For i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            With ws.Cells(i, 1)
                'count #N/A in A:C for this row
                If Application.CountIf(.Resize(1, 3), CVErr(xlErrNA)) = 3 Then
                    .EntireRow.ClearContents 'clear
                    '.EntireRow.Delete       '...or delete
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    Next x
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("#N/A were successfully cleaned")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great! I really appreciate your help